# Tomcat - Multiple hosts in JDBC connection

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

We've just upgraded one of our applications from JBOSS to Tomcat.  In the JBOSS config, we had a "|" separated list of host names on the connection url:

```
<connection-url>
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname1:1522:servicename|jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname2:1522:servicename 
</connection-url >
```

Followed by  a delimiter tag: `<url-delimeter>|</url-delimeter>`

In the new Tomcat config (server.xml) it generates an error when I use the same config URL:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDatasource"
          auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname1>:1522:<servicename>|jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostanme2>:1522:<servicename>"
          username="username" password="password"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?  Or how I can get it to use the multiple hosts?

The error I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid" )
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you'll give *one* connection URL in the form host:port:sid. Tomcat [doesn't know](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) about multiple URLs to (what should be) a single database.

What's the semantics behind this anyways? If both are the same, why provide two hosts. If they're clustered, just provide a single address for the cluster. Or use a driver (other than thin) that can understand multiple hostnames in its part of the URL (following the @).

Comment: It's a clustered DB, so the 2 hosts are pointing to the same DB.

Do you know which drivers (other than thin) can understand multiple hostnames?

Comment: see the answer to the question that I've linked as duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems that's the only way to point to multiple DB's within a single datasource.